# Use of #pragma in C

Tags: c, pragma

What are some uses of `#pragma` in C, with examples?

Comment: `#pragma` directive survives the pre-processing stage. Unlike `#include` and `#define`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does #pragma once mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776910/what-does-pragma-once-mean-in-c)

Comment: @smwikipedia you mean some pragmas survive? #pragma once is a preprocessor directive but #pragma pack is a compiler directive

Answer (score 77):

`#pragma` is for compiler directives that are machine-specific or operating-system-specific, i.e. it tells the compiler to do something, set some option, take some action, override some default, etc. that may or may not apply to all machines and operating systems.

See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805.aspx) for more info.

Comment: "that may or may not apply to all machines and operating systems." - and different compilers on the same machine. And which might mean different things on different compilers.

Answer (score 62):

`#pragma` is used to do something implementation-specific in C, i.e. be pragmatic for the current context rather than ideologically dogmatic.

The one I regularly use is `#pragma pack(1)` where I'm trying to squeeze more out of my memory space on embedded solutions, with arrays of structures that would otherwise end up with 8 byte alignment.

Pity we don't have a `#dogma` yet. That would be fun ;)

Comment: @ShaneMacLaughlin, Doesn't `pragma(1)` actully improves speed too? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318410/pragma-pack-effect#comment31382945_3318475

Comment: @Pacerier, typically not.  As per jalfs comments, data that is aligned on a 4 byte boundary for 32 bit processors or 8 byte boundary for 64 bit processors will typically be loaded and stored in a single operation.  Data that is aligned on smaller boundaries will take multiple operations to load or store.  This is slower.

Answer (score 43):

I would generally try to avoid the use of #pragmas if possible, since they're extremely compiler-dependent and non-portable.  If you want to use them in a portable fashion, you'll have to surround every pragma with a `#if`/`#endif` pair.  GCC discourages the use of pragmas, and really only supports some of them for compatibility with other compilers; GCC has other ways of doing the same things that other compilers use pragmas for.

For example, here's how you'd ensure that a structure is packed tightly (i.e. no padding between members) in MSVC:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct PackedStructure
{
  char a;
  int b;
  short c;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
// sizeof(PackedStructure) == 7
```

Here's how you'd do the same thing in GCC:

```
struct PackedStructure __attribute__((__packed__))
{
  char a;
  int b;
  short c;
};
// sizeof(PackedStructure == 7)
```

The GCC code is more portable, because if you want to compile that with a non-GCC compiler, all you have to do is

`#define __attribute__(x)`

Whereas if you want to port the MSVC code, you have to surround each pragma with a `#if`/`#endif` pair.  Not pretty.

Comment: So if I want to compile the GCC code on MSVC and need to pack the structure how exactly do I do it?

Comment: For gcc, it's 
`struct __attribute__((__packed__)) PackedStructure`

Comment: #pragma once is not realistically "compiler dependent and non-portable".  It's supported on every major platform and many not-major platforms..   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once#Portability

Comment: Note that C99 and C11 both contain (C11) [§6.10.6 Pragma directives](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.6) and ¶1 _Any such pragma that is not recognized by the implementation is ignored._ Even C90 says that, though it was in section §6.8.6.  (This makes GCC non-compliant if it runs `hack` when it encounters a pragma it doesn't recognize, as it used to do once upon a very, very long time ago – see [`#pragma` and GCC](http://toni.technetium.be/hacker/pragma.htm), etc.)

Comment: GCC's syntax is always totally f-ed compared to all other alternatives - just look at what they did to inline assembly - ugh.  Anyway, might not need that eye-cancer for structure packing - see: 
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Layout-Pragmas.html#Structure-Layout-Pragmas

Answer (score 17):

Putting `#pragma once` at the top of your header file will ensure that it is only included once. Note that `#pragma once` is not standard C99, but supported by most modern compilers.

An alternative is to use include guards (e.g. `#ifndef MY_FILE #define MY_FILE ... #endif /* MY_FILE */`)

Answer (score 7):

what i feel is `#pragma` is a directive where if you want the code to be location specific .say a situation where you want the program counter to read from the specific address where the ISR is written then you can specify ISR at that location using `#pragma vector=ADC12_VECTOR` and followd by interrupt rotines name and its description

Answer (score 6):

My best advice is to look at your compiler's documentation, because pragmas are by definition implementation-specific.  For instance, in embedded projects I've used them to locate code and data in different sections, or declare interrupt handlers.  i.e.:

```
#pragma code BANK1
#pragma data BANK2

#pragma INT3 TimerHandler
```

Comment: All pragmas are implementation-specific -- except the #pragma STDC ... pragmas, which are standardized across all platforms (addition to C99).

Answer (score 6):

All answers above make nice explanations for `#pragma` but I wanted to a add small example

I just want to explain a `simple OpenMP example` that demonstrate some uses of `#pragma` to doing its work

> OpenMp `briefly` is an implementation for multi-platform shared-memory
>   parallel programming
>   (then we can say it's `machine-specific` or `operating-system-specific`)

let's go to the example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>// compile with: /openmp

int main() {
   #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
   {
      int i = omp_get_thread_num();
      printf_s("Hello from thread %d\n", i);
   }
}
```

the output is

```
Hello from thread 0
Hello from thread 1
Hello from thread 2
Hello from thread 3

Note that the order of output can vary on different machines.
```

now let me tell you what `#pragma` did...

it tells the OS to run the some block of code on 4 threads

this is just one of `many many applications` you can do with the little `#pragma`

sorry for the outside sample `OpenMP`

Answer (score 3):

This is a preprocessor directive that can be used to turn on or off certain features.

It is of two types `#pragma startup`, `#pragma exit` and `#pragma warn`.

`#pragma startup` allows us to specify functions called upon program startup.

`#pragma exit` allows us to specify functions called upon program exit.

`#pragma warn` tells the computer to suppress any warning or not.

Many other `#pragma` styles can be used to control the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

`#pragma startup` is a directive which is used to call a function before the main function and to call another function after the main function, e.g.

```
#pragma startup func1
#pragma exit func2
```

Here, `func1` runs before `main` and `func2` runs afterwards.

NOTE: This code works only in Turbo-C compiler. To achieve this functionality in GCC, you can declare `func1` and `func2` like this:

```
void __attribute__((constructor)) func1();
void __attribute__((destructor)) func2();
```

Answer (score 2):

To sum it up, `#pragma` tells the compiler to do stuff. Here are a couple of ways I use it:

- `#pragma` can be used to ignore compiler warnings. For example, to make GCC shut up about implicit function declarations, you can write:

  ```
  #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wimplicit-function-declaration"
  ```

  An older version of [`libportable`](//github.com/aaronryank/libportable) does this [portably](https://github.com/aaronryank/libportable/commit/6823a4f6cec2c36efa8d6004775dbd9e444f7570#diff-7952dc5980168aa9b8e5064c38af989eR107).
- `#pragma once`, when written at the top of a header file, will cause said header file to be included once. `libportable` [checks](https://github.com/aaronryank/libportable/blob/master/portable.h#L156) for pragma once support.