# Structure padding and packing

Tags: c, struct, structure, padding, packing

Consider:

```
struct mystruct_A
{
   char a;
   int b;
   char c;
} x;

struct mystruct_B
{
   int b;
   char a;
} y;
```

The sizes of the structures are 12 and 8 respectively.

Are these structures padded or packed?

When does padding or packing take place?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member

Comment: The Lost Art of C Structure Packing - http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/

Comment: `padding` makes things bigger. `packing` makes things smaller. Totally different.

Comment: @Paolo, that Lost Art link does not show what happens when there is pointer-alignment and the above where two ints might be one after another.

Comment: Related, for C++: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287060/c-class-packing-member-alignment

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318410/pragma-pack-effect

Answer (score 389, accepted):

**Padding** [aligns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) structure members to "natural" address boundaries - say, `int` members would have offsets, which are `mod(4) == 0` on 32-bit platform. Padding is on by default. It inserts the following "gaps" into your first structure:

```
struct mystruct_A {
    char a;
    char gap_0[3]; /* inserted by compiler: for alignment of b */
    int b;
    char c;
    char gap_1[3]; /* -"-: for alignment of the whole struct in an array */
} x;
```

**Packing**, on the other hand prevents compiler from doing padding - this has to be explicitly requested - under GCC it's `__attribute__((__packed__))`, so the following:

```
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) mystruct_A {
    char a;
    int b;
    char c;
};
```

would produce structure of size `6` on a 32-bit architecture.

A note though - unaligned memory access is slower on architectures that allow it (like x86 and amd64), and is explicitly prohibited on *strict alignment architectures* like SPARC.

Comment: I wonder: is prohibition of unaligned memory on the spark means that it can not deal with an usual byte arrays? Struct packing as I know mostly used in transmitting(i.e networking) a data, when you need to cast a byte array to a struct, and be sure that an array fit to a struct fields. If the spark can not do that, how those working at all?!

Comment: That's exactly why, if you look at IP, UDP, and TCP header layouts, you'd see that all integer fields are aligned.

Comment: The "Lost Art of C Structure Packing" explains padding and packing ptimisations - http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/

Comment: /* malloc() always provides aligned memory */
    cptr = malloc(sizeof(int) + 1);
     /* Increment the pointer by one, making it misaligned */
    iptr = (int *) ++cptr;
     /* Dereference it as an int pointer, causing an unaligned access */
    *iptr = 42;
Above code will give bus error. But if I stopped packing of a structure, accessing its variables will not give any ? Why?

Comment: This may have just saved my day. Was wondering why the hell my struct using fwrite was always aligning along 32-bit boundaries. Thanks for the detailed answer and the __packed__ attribute.

Comment: Does first member have to come first? I thought arragement is totally up to the implementation, and cannot be relied upon (even from version to version).

Comment: @allyourcode I believe you may be right in terms of the C standard, however when you pack a structure no compiler will mess with the order of fields.  The whole purpose of packing is to give the programmer control over what the structure looks like in memory.

Comment: good read : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/structure-member-alignment-padding-and-data-packing/

Comment: +allyourcode The standard guarantees that the order of the members will be preserved and that the first member will start at 0 offset.

Comment: the sizeof struct __attribute__((__packed__)) mystruct_A {
    char a;
    int b;
    char c;
}; in my computer give me 9

Comment: @NikolaiFetissov I dont think that unaligned access is slower on modern x86 CPU only slower when the memory access cross a cache line boundaries which is 64 bytes otherwise speed is will be identical.

Comment: Can u please tell what would be the size of mystruct_A if packed attribute is removed in same last example in ur answer

Comment: Why are shorts aligned on 2 byte boundaries and not 4 byte boundaries. If the goal is to avoid accessing memory across word boundaries for performance, why have shorts be aligned to 2? Why not have them be aligned to 4 just like integers are?

Answer (score 156):

(*The above answers explained the reason quite clearly, but seems not totally clear about the size of padding, so, I will add an answer according to what I learned from **[The Lost Art of Structure Packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/)**, it has evolved to not limit to `C`, but also applicable to `Go`, `Rust`.*)

---

### Memory align (for struct)

**Rules:**

- Before each individual member, there will be padding so that to make it start at an address that is divisible by its alignment requirement.
  E.g., on many systems, an `int` should start at an address divisible by 4 and a `short` by 2.
- `char` and `char[]` are special, could be any memory address, so they don't need padding before them.
- For `struct`, other than the alignment need for each individual member, the size of whole struct itself will be aligned to a size divisible by strictest alignment requirement of any of its members, by padding at end.
  E.g., on many systems, if struct's largest member is `int` then by divisible by 4, if `short` then by 2.

**Order of member:**

- The order of member might affect actual size of struct, so take that in mind.
  E.g., the `stu_c` and `stu_d` from example below have the same members, but in different order, and result in different size for the 2 structs.

---

### Address in memory (for struct)

**Empty space**:

- Empty space between 2 structs could be used by non-struct variables that could fit in.
  e.g in `test_struct_address()` below, the variable `x` resides between adjacent struct `g` and `h`.
  No matter whether `x` is declared, `h`'s address won't change, `x` just reused the empty space that `g` wasted.
  Similar case for `y`.

---

### Example

(*for 64 bit system*)

**memory_align.c**:

```
/**
 * Memory align & padding - for struct.
 * compile: gcc memory_align.c
 * execute: ./a.out
 */ 
#include <stdio.h>

// size is 8, 4 + 1, then round to multiple of 4 (int's size),
struct stu_a {
    int i;
    char c;
};

// size is 16, 8 + 1, then round to multiple of 8 (long's size),
struct stu_b {
    long l;
    char c;
};

// size is 24, l need padding by 4 before it, then round to multiple of 8 (long's size),
struct stu_c {
    int i;
    long l;
    char c;
};

// size is 16, 8 + 4 + 1, then round to multiple of 8 (long's size),
struct stu_d {
    long l;
    int i;
    char c;
};

// size is 16, 8 + 4 + 1, then round to multiple of 8 (double's size),
struct stu_e {
    double d;
    int i;
    char c;
};

// size is 24, d need align to 8, then round to multiple of 8 (double's size),
struct stu_f {
    int i;
    double d;
    char c;
};

// size is 4,
struct stu_g {
    int i;
};

// size is 8,
struct stu_h {
    long l;
};

// test - padding within a single struct,
int test_struct_padding() {
    printf("%s: %ld\n", "stu_a", sizeof(struct stu_a));
    printf("%s: %ld\n", "stu_b", sizeof(struct stu_b));
    printf("%s: %ld\n", "stu_c", sizeof(struct stu_c));
    printf("%s: %ld\n", "stu_d", sizeof(struct stu_d));
    printf("%s: %ld\n", "stu_e", sizeof(struct stu_e));
    printf("%s: %ld\n", "stu_f", sizeof(struct stu_f));

    printf("%s: %ld\n", "stu_g", sizeof(struct stu_g));
    printf("%s: %ld\n", "stu_h", sizeof(struct stu_h));

    return 0;
}

// test - address of struct,
int test_struct_address() {
    printf("%s: %ld\n", "stu_g", sizeof(struct stu_g));
    printf("%s: %ld\n", "stu_h", sizeof(struct stu_h));
    printf("%s: %ld\n", "stu_f", sizeof(struct stu_f));

    struct stu_g g;
    struct stu_h h;
    struct stu_f f1;
    struct stu_f f2;
    int x = 1;
    long y = 1;

    printf("address of %s: %p\n", "g", &g);
    printf("address of %s: %p\n", "h", &h);
    printf("address of %s: %p\n", "f1", &f1);
    printf("address of %s: %p\n", "f2", &f2);
    printf("address of %s: %p\n", "x", &x);
    printf("address of %s: %p\n", "y", &y);

    // g is only 4 bytes itself, but distance to next struct is 16 bytes(on 64 bit system) or 8 bytes(on 32 bit system),
    printf("space between %s and %s: %ld\n", "g", "h", (long)(&h) - (long)(&g));

    // h is only 8 bytes itself, but distance to next struct is 16 bytes(on 64 bit system) or 8 bytes(on 32 bit system),
    printf("space between %s and %s: %ld\n", "h", "f1", (long)(&f1) - (long)(&h));

    // f1 is only 24 bytes itself, but distance to next struct is 32 bytes(on 64 bit system) or 24 bytes(on 32 bit system),
    printf("space between %s and %s: %ld\n", "f1", "f2", (long)(&f2) - (long)(&f1));

    // x is not a struct, and it reuse those empty space between struts, which exists due to padding, e.g between g & h,
    printf("space between %s and %s: %ld\n", "x", "f2", (long)(&x) - (long)(&f2));
    printf("space between %s and %s: %ld\n", "g", "x", (long)(&x) - (long)(&g));

    // y is not a struct, and it reuse those empty space between struts, which exists due to padding, e.g between h & f1,
    printf("space between %s and %s: %ld\n", "x", "y", (long)(&y) - (long)(&x));
    printf("space between %s and %s: %ld\n", "h", "y", (long)(&y) - (long)(&h));

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    test_struct_padding();
    // test_struct_address();

    return 0;
}
```

**Execution result - *`test_struct_padding()`*:**

```
stu_a: 8
stu_b: 16
stu_c: 24
stu_d: 16
stu_e: 16
stu_f: 24
stu_g: 4
stu_h: 8
```

**Execution result - *`test_struct_address()`*:**

```
stu_g: 4
stu_h: 8
stu_f: 24
address of g: 0x7fffd63a95d0  // struct variable - address dividable by 16,
address of h: 0x7fffd63a95e0  // struct variable - address dividable by 16,
address of f1: 0x7fffd63a95f0 // struct variable - address dividable by 16,
address of f2: 0x7fffd63a9610 // struct variable - address dividable by 16,
address of x: 0x7fffd63a95dc  // non-struct variable - resides within the empty space between struct variable g & h.
address of y: 0x7fffd63a95e8  // non-struct variable - resides within the empty space between struct variable h & f1.
space between g and h: 16
space between h and f1: 16
space between f1 and f2: 32
space between x and f2: -52
space between g and x: 12
space between x and y: 12
space between h and y: 8
```

Thus address start for each variable is g:d0 x:dc h:e0 y:e8

[image]

Comment: "Rules" actually made it very clear, I couldn't find straightforward rule anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: @PervezAlam The book `<The Lost Art of C Structure Packing>`, explains the rules pretty well, even thought it's a little longer than this answer. The book is available freely online: http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/

Comment: I will give it a try, btw is it limited to Structure packing? Just curios as I liked the explanation in book.

Comment: @PervezAlam It's a very short book, mainly focus on technology that would reduce memory footprint of c program, it takes only at most several days to finish reading.

Comment: As per your first point: does that mean that padding is also added between structs. That is to make the first element of the next struct to a divisible address?

Comment: @AkshayImmanuelD Yes, each individual member obey rule 1, and the start address of first member is also the start address of the struct itself.

Comment: What happens to the padding bytes between 2 struct? Isn't that also a waste of memory?

Comment: @AkshayImmanuelD To achieve alignment, padding is necessary. A well designed struct might contains proper amount of members in proper order, and the padding is minimized, thus that padding might won't be that significant for the overall memory.

Comment: Makes sense why some coding standards say to arrange structures from largest to smallest members

Comment: From my previous comment-> "does that mean that padding is also added between structs. That is to make the first element of the next struct to a divisible address". I read somewhere that padding can never be between structures. Padding at the end of one struct makes sure the beginning of the new struct is aligned

Comment: @AkshayImmanuelD The space between 2 structs, don't actually belong to the first struct, because other non-struct variable could reuse it when possible. Check the updated answer, mainly the `Address in memory - for struct` part.

Comment: So the compiler could place static duration variables in the gaps between structs

Comment: So the size of a struct will always be an even number

Comment: I think "Address in memory - for struct" is not very clear, at least to me. It would help if you can explain a bit further.

Comment: @ValidusOculus I modified the answer a bit, please check if it's more reasonable now.

Comment: @EricWang Thank you. I just realized that it was 'the possible' part in your sentence " the possible largest individual struct member is 16 bytes" therefore I was thinking where the hell 16 byte in that struct came from LOL. Thank you!

Comment: @EricWang For the part 'n * 16', what 'n' refers to? Do you mean that all the struct addresses starts from 16 byte aligned address?

Comment: @ValidusOculus Yes, it means 16 byte aligned.

Comment: @Eric Wang Thank you!

Comment: Great answer but I don't follow why the address has to be divisible by 16. I ran this code on my machine and `address of g: 0x7ffcccbd8198`. I also don't understand why this would be generally true, since it would imply that if you had an array of structs, each would be padded out to 16 bytes so that all their addresses are 16-byte aligned, but of course that's not the case.

Comment: (I have a 64-bit machine fyi)

Comment: @sevko The reason is the max possible member is 16 bytes. But when the struct only contains a single char as member, it could start at any address, I have updated the answer with that. Regarding your output, I am not sure. I did more test and they still following the rules. And, I am also not totally sure about whether array of structs has different rules. Honestly I am not a c expert, I use other languages at work most of the time. Could you ask another question to confirm about this, and may update the answer if the rules above are proven wrong?

Comment: `Before each individual member, there will be padding so that to make it start at an address that is divisible by its size.
e.g on a 64-bit system, int should start at an address **divisible by 4**, and long by 8, short by 2.` @EricWang as per the above rule int should start at the address divisible by 4 and the struct g only contains an int member so the address of g should be divisible by 4. In that case address of g is divisible by 4 in your machine and @sevko machine.

Comment: @sevko @user218867 `Struct address starts from (n * 16) bytes.` is not true. Struct address starts from first member's address. The first member's address is determined by the struct's alignment requirement, and a struct has the alignment of its widest member. So, address of `stu_g` is divisible by 4, address of `stu_f` is divisible by 4. The rule `Before each individual...` is not applied to first member of struct(That is applied to variable, not field). For `struct stu { char c; int *p; };`, its address starts from any addresses divisible by 4/8 depending on machine type, not any addresses.

Answer (score 63):

I know this question is old and most answers here explains padding really well, but while trying to understand it myself I figured having a "visual" image of what is happening helped.

The processor reads the memory in "chunks" of a definite size (word). Say the processor word is 8 bytes long. It will look at the memory as a big row of 8 bytes building blocks. Every time it needs to get some information from the memory, it will reach one of those blocks and get it.

[image: Variables Alignment]

As seem in the image above, doesn't matter where a Char (1 byte long) is, since it will be inside one of those blocks, requiring the CPU to process only 1 word.

When we deal with data larger than one byte, like a 4 byte int or a 8 byte double, the way they are aligned in the memory makes a difference on how many words will have to be processed by the CPU. If 4-byte chunks are aligned in a way they always fit the inside of a block (memory address being a multiple of 4) only one word will have to be processed. Otherwise a chunk of 4-bytes could have part of itself on one block and part on another, requiring the processor to process 2 words to read this data.

The same applies to a 8-byte double, except now it must be in a memory address multiple of 8 to guarantee it will always be inside a block.

This considers a 8-byte word processor, but the concept applies to other sizes of words.

The padding works by filling the gaps between those data to make sure they are aligned with those blocks, thus improving the performance while reading the memory.

However, as stated on others answers, sometimes the space matters more then performance itself. Maybe you are processing lots of data on a computer that doesn't have much RAM (swap space could be used but it is MUCH slower). You could arrange the variables in the program until the least padding is done (as it was greatly exemplified in some other answers) but if that's not enough you could explicitly disable padding, which is what **packing** is.

Comment: This doesn't explain structure packing but it illustrates CPU word alignment quite nicely.

Comment: Did you draw that in paint? :-)

Comment: @CiroSantilli709大抓捕六四事件法轮功, it was on gimp, but I guess I'd have saved some time doing it on paint though haha

Comment: Even better since open source (Y)

Comment: It is also very convenient when reading structures from files. One can simply read into a buffer then `memcpy` etc. directly into a struct.

Comment: You underscore a very important concept, which is that processors read memory in definite sizes (word size). This could be 4 or 8, depending on the platform architecture, but it is required to know this if one is to draw the struct/class on paper to help derive its size, compiler padding, and alignment.

I can almost guarantee that many of us incorrectly assume that the processor reads 64 bytes of memory at a time (since that is the size of cache lines on most modern PCs), when in reality there is a difference between READ and LOAD. 

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: There is no picture in your asnwer. Can you update picture or give a valid link?

Answer (score 26):

Structure packing suppresses structure padding, padding used when alignment matters most, packing used when space matters most.

Some compilers provide `#pragma` to suppress padding or to make it packed to n number of bytes. Some provide keywords to do this. Generally pragma which is used for modifying structure padding will be in the below format (depends on compiler):

```
#pragma pack(n)
```

For example ARM provides the `__packed` keyword to suppress structure padding. Go through your compiler manual to learn more about this.

**So a packed structure is a structure without padding.**

Generally packed structures will be used

- to save space
- to format a data structure to transmit over network using some
  protocol (this is not a good practice of course because you need to
  deal with endianness)

Answer (score 6):

Padding and packing are just two aspects of the same thing:

- packing or alignment is the size to which each member is rounded off
- padding is the extra space added to match the alignment

In `mystruct_A`, assuming a default alignment of 4, each member is aligned on a multiple of 4 bytes. Since the size of `char` is 1, the padding for `a` and `c` is 4 - 1 = 3 bytes while no padding is required for `int b` which is already 4 bytes. It works the same way for `mystruct_B`.

Answer (score 5):

The variables are stored at any addresses divisible by its alignment(by its size generally). So, padding/packing is not just for struct only. Actually, *all data has its own alignment requirement*:

```c
int main(void) {
    // We assume the `c` is stored as first byte of machine word
    // as a convenience! If the `c` was stored as a last byte of previous
    // word, there is no need to pad bytes before variable `i`
    // because `i` is automatically aligned in a new word.

    char      c;  // starts from any addresses divisible by 1(any addresses).
    char pad[3];  // not-used memory for `i` to start from its address.
    int32_t   i;  // starts from any addresses divisible by 4.
```

This is similar to struct, but there are some differences. First, we can say there are two kinds of padding— a) To start each member from its address properly, some bytes are inserted between members. b) To start next struct instance from its address properly, some bytes are appended to each struct:

```c
// Example for rule 1 below.
struct st {
    char      c;  // starts from any addresses divisible by 4, not 1.
    char pad[3];  // not-used memory for `i` to start from its address.
    int32_t   i;  // starts from any addresses divisible by 4.
};

// Example for rule 2 below.
struct st {
    int32_t   i;  // starts from any addresses divisible by 4.
    char      c;  // starts from any addresses.
    char pad[3];  // not-used memory for next `st`(or anything that has same
                  // alignment requirement) to start from its own address.
};
```

1. The struct's first member always starts from any addresses divisible by struct's own alignment requirement which is determined by largest member's alignment requirement(here `4`, alignment of `int32_t`). This is different with normal variables. The normal variables can start any addresses divisible by its alignment, but it is not the case for struct's first member. As you know, the address of a struct is the same as the address of its first member.
2. There can be additional padded trailing bytes inside a struct, making next struct(or next element in an array of structs) starting from its own address. Think of `struct st arr[2];`. To make `arr[1]`(`arr[1]`'s first member) starting from an address divisible by 4, we should append 3 bytes at the end of each struct.

This is what i learned from [The Lost Art of Structure Packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/).

NOTE : You can investigate what the data type's alignment requirement is through `_Alignof` operator. Also, you can get member's offset inside a struct through `offsetof` macro.

Answer (score 4):

Rules for padding:

1. Every member of the struct should be at an address divisible by its size.
   Padding is inserted between elements or at the end of the struct to make sure this rule is met. This is done for easier and more efficient Bus access by the hardware.
2. Padding at the end of the struct is decided based on the size of the largest member of the struct.

Why Rule 2:
Consider the following struct,

[image: Struct 1]

If we were to create an array(of 2 structs) of this struct,
No padding will be  required at the end:

[image: Struct1 array]

Therefore, size of struct = 8 bytes

Assume we were to create another struct as below:

[image: Struct 2]

If we were to create an array of this struct,
there are 2 possibilities, of the number of bytes of padding required at the end.

A. If we add 3 bytes at the end and align it for int and not Long:

[image: Struct2 array aligned to int]

B. If we add 7 bytes at the end and align it for Long:

[image: Struct2 array aligned to Long]

The start address of the second array is a multiple of 8(i.e 24).
The size of the struct = 24 bytes

Therefore, by aligning the start address of the next array of the struct to a multiple of the largest member(i.e if we were to create an array of this struct, the first address of the second array must start at an address which is a multiple of the largest member of the struct. Here it is, 24(3 * 8)), we can calculate the number of padding bytes required at the end.

Answer (score 2):

> Are these structures padded or packed?

They're padded.

The only possibility that *initially* springs to mind, where they could be packed, is if `char` and `int` were the same size, so that the minimum size of the `char/int/char` structure would allow for no padding, ditto for the `int/char` structure.

However, that would require both `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(char)` to be *four* (to get the twelve and eight sizes). The whole theory falls apart since it's guaranteed by the standard that `sizeof(char)` is *always* one.

Were `char` and `int` the same width, the sizes would be one and one, *not* four and four. So, in order to then get a size of twelve, there would have to be padding after the final field.

---

> When does padding or packing take place?

Whenever the compiler implementation wants it to. Compilers are free to insert padding between fields, and following the final field (but *not* before the first field).

This is usually done for performance as some types perform better when they're aligned on specific boundaries. There are even some architectures that will refuse to function (i.e, crash) is you try to access unaligned data (yes, I'm looking at *you,* ARM).

You can generally control packing/padding (which is really opposite ends of the same spectrum) with implementation-specific features such as `#pragma pack`. Even if you *cannot* do that in your specific implementation, you can check your code at compile time to ensure it meets your requirement (using standard C features, not implementation-specific stuff).

For example:

```cpp
// C11 or better ...
#include <assert.h>
struct strA { char a; int  b; char c; } x;
struct strB { int  b; char a;         } y;
static_assert(sizeof(struct strA) == sizeof(char)*2 + sizeof(int), "No padding allowed");
static_assert(sizeof(struct strB) == sizeof(char)   + sizeof(int), "No padding allowed");
```

Something like this will refuse to compile if there is any padding in those structures.

Answer (score 1):

Structure packing is only done when you tell your compiler explicitly to pack the structure. Padding is what you're seeing. Your 32-bit system is padding each field to word alignment. If you had told your compiler to pack the structures, they'd be 6 and 5 bytes, respectively. Don't do that though. It's not portable and makes compilers generate much slower (and sometimes even buggy) code.

Answer (score 1):

***There are no buts about it!*** Who want to grasp the subject must do the following ones,

> - Peruse [The Lost Art of Structure Packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/) written by Eric S.    Raymond
> - Glance at [Eric's code example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38144117/4990642)
> - Last but not least, don't forget the following rule about padding that    **a struct is aligned to the largest type’s alignment
>     requirements.**

Answer (score -1):

Data structure alignment is the way data is arranged and accessed in computer memory. It consists of two separate but related issues: data alignment and [data structure padding](http://www.firmcodes.com/structure-padding-and-packing-in-c-example/). When a modern computer reads from or writes to a memory address, it will do this in word sized chunks (e.g. 4 byte chunks on a 32-bit system) or larger. Data alignment means putting the data at a memory address equal to some multiple of the word size, which increases the system’s performance due to the way the CPU handles memory. To align the data, it may be necessary to insert some meaningless bytes between the end of the last data structure and the start of the next, which is data structure padding.

1. In order to align the data in memory,  one or more empty bytes (addresses) are inserted (or left empty) between memory addresses which are allocated for other structure members while memory allocation. This concept is called structure padding.
2. Architecture of a computer processor is such a way that it can read 1 word (4 byte in 32 bit processor) from memory at a time.
3. To make use of this advantage of processor, data are always aligned as 4 bytes package which leads to insert empty addresses between other member’s address.
4. Because of this structure padding concept in C, size of the structure is always not same as what we think.

Comment: Why do you need to link to the same article **5 times** in your answer? Please keep only one link to the example. Also, since you're linking to your article, you need to disclose that fact.