# How to align a kmalloc() address in linux

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel

I have a requirement in kernel space wherein i have to program device register with 64K aligned address. Currently i am using kmalloc() to allocate memory but not sure how to align this 64K. Does linux provide a API which does this?
Do i need to write my own code to do the same?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310641/how-to-perform-data-structure-alignment-with-kmalloc

Answer (score 2):

Try following approach:

First calling kmem_cache_create(...) function to create a cache pool for your structure which should be 64K aligned like following:

```
    buff_64k_cachep = kmem_cache_create("buff_64k_cache",
                                     sizeof(struct test_struct),
                                     1<<16, /* 64k alignment */
                                     flags,
                                     );
```

Then calling kmem_cache_alloc(...) and kmem_cache_free(...) to allocate and free the buffers you needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am only supposed to use kmalloc().  Doing some reading on net i see few answers: For eg if i want a memory of 2K, allocate 4K of memory, add 64K offset to the kmalloc() address and then &~(0x10000) to make it 64K aligned. I quite didn't understand this as we are wasting memory here. I also got confused when they say "bit" and "byte" alignment are different. Please help me out here.

Comment: After Googling and some think throw, i finally arrived at this logic. pusedocode :  unal_addr = (Memory address + alignment_no);        aligned_addr = unal_addr - (unal_addr%alignment_no) should give the required alignment. Please let me know if this is not right.

Comment: i dont' think so... your aligned_address should be larger than unalligned address