# Uint16 getting size of 32bit after compiling with GCC

Tags: c, gcc

I'm quite puzzled by the following code:

```
typedef struct
{
    Uint16          first:8;   // has a size of 8 bit
    Uint16          second:8;  // has a size of 8 bit
    Uint16          third;     // has a size of 32 bit; what's wrong here?
} TSomeStruct;
```

I expected "third" to have a size of 16 bit instead of 32 bit. I'm sure the mistake must be on my part.

Background: It's not my code base and I'm performing verification on it. Since it's written for an embedded system and a proprietary compiler which I don't have I'm just generating the syntax tree with the "-fdump-translation-unit" option and perform my verification on that. But Uint16 should be 16 bits long in GCC as well so that shouldn't be the problem, right?

Comment: What is `Uint16` typedef'ed to? And how did you determine the size?

Comment: How did you check its size ? Did you perchance do a `sizeof` of the entire structure ?

Comment: `it's written for an embedded system` - what architecture was it written for?

Comment: what is `Uint16`? could you use the, imo, better `uint16_t`?

Comment: Oh boy, coming from C# with builtin types that have names like these I just assumed that it was a standard type in C as well. My bad. It was defined to
    typedef unsigned int     Uint16;
Is there any way to force gcc to use 16 bits instead of 32 bits for int? Otherwise the enums are getting too long even if I correct this typedef.

Comment: if, and only if, the stdint.h header has been ported for your architecture, you can use uint16_t to force 16 bit integers. otherwise, you have to read the docs of the compiler and the arch to find out what size of integers are available.

Comment: Btw. @DanielFischer: If you answer this question with your tip I will gladly accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Uint16` is not a standard type in C, so its size depends on what it's `typedef`ed to.

It may be `typedef`ed to `unsigned int` because that is guaranteed to be 16 bits in the proprietary compiler for the embedded platform. But then it would become a 32-bit type when compiled with a current gcc for x86 platforms.

> Is there any way to force gcc to use 16 bits instead of 32 bits for `int`?

I know of none. If you have access to the code, using `short` instead of `int` will very likely work. If `stdint.h` is available, `uint16_t`/`int16_t` will work (unless there is no 16-bit integer type on the platform).

Comment: "`Uint16` is not a standard type in C, so its size depends on what it's typedefed to." Actually there is a high probability that it's exactly what it's name suggests. An unsigend integer of 16 bit width. It was pretty wide spread practice in embedded software to create fixed size typedefs long before C99 came up with this.

Comment: @junix In this specific case, it was `typedef`ed to `unsigned int`, so it wasn't an unsigned 16-bit type when the OP used gcc. That's the whole reason for this question.

Comment: Right. Didn't notice the comment of Lichtblitz regarding the `typedef unsigned int Uint16`.

Answer (score 2):

Structure members a usually padded to a word size.

In order to force compiler to pack the structure there are different ways.
I prefer the folloiwng:

```
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) packed_struct {
    unsigned char a;
    unsigned char b;
    unsigned char c;
};
```

In this case `sizeof(packed_struct)` will give you `3`.

Unfortunately, you will pay for this by program performance.

Comment: Normally(1), padding is only inserted if necessary to make the next member suitably aligned. (1)In my limited experience.

Comment: @DanielFischer This really depends on the compiler settings and the architecture compiled for. Usually compilers optimize for fast (simple) access of structure members. For architectures not supporting reading of half words the fastest way is to place members in words. Otherwise the compiler would have to insert instructions to shift and mask the sub-word values which is ineficcient in terms of runtime.

Comment: @Alex: Maybe it's worth noting how to "persuade" the compiler to increase the density of a structure: By placing `#pragma pack(1)` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318410/pragma-pack-effect for details) in front of the structure you can force the compiler to stop inserting padding. Unfortunately this also introduces a performance penalty in terms of runtime.

Comment: @junix, yes I know about this option, possibly I should mention it.