# How to make a data type smaller than 32 bits

Tags: c, memory, byte, sizeof, bit

Well, I've created a bit field

```
typedef struct 
{
    unsigned bit : 1;
}BIT;
```

and the sizeof operator returns 4...ergo said struct isn't really a bit, rather 32. Is there a way to force a c struct to be below said value? is it all system dependent? (my book for one says a char is only 1 byte, whereas for me sizeof(char) returns 4...)

Comment: I'm dubious that your 'sizeof(char)' returns 4.

Comment: Size of char is not necessarily `1` byte always. It depends on machine architecture.

Comment: Probably you had `sizeof('a')` or so as returning 4. Character constants in C are not of type `char` but of type `int`.

Comment: @haccks, no, no, no. `sizeof` is *defined* to return the number of `char` in an object and so `sizeof(char)` is always 1. If your compiler is telling you something different, it is definitively not a C compiler.

Comment: @JensGustedt; Interesting! You are right. Then how could I calculate size of `char`?

Comment: @haccks: type `char` has size 1, by definition; the macro `CHAR_BITS` tells you how many bits are in a single `char` (at least 8, but could be more).  Whether a `char` value maps to a single byte on the target platform is up to the implementation.  For example, one old architecture (PDP?) used 36-bit words, which could hold 5 7-bit character values with one bit left over.  Mapping a `char` value on to that architecture would be a challenge.

Comment: @JohnBode; I read that on some machine `char` is of 2 bytes. Then how could I calculate this size ?

Comment: @haccks In C a "byte" is not necessarily 8 bits but "addressable unit of data storage large enough to hold any member of the basic character set of the execution environment". It also must be >= 8 bits. IWO, a  `char`.  So `char` always has a size of 1.  Outside of this C language definition, a "byte" is now largely understood to be 8 bits (it was not always so).  So a `char` could be 2 "outside of C definition" bytes.

Comment: @haccks: A C `char` does not necessarily have to map to an 8-bit byte on the target machine.  Imagine a word-addressed architecture where the smallest addressable unit of storage is 16 bits wide (I think some Crays are an example of this).  A single `char` value will be mapped to a 16-bit word.  Or you may be thinking of the `wchar` type, which was introduced to handle character sets that couldn't fit in ASCII or EBCDIC (and which has been superceded by Unicode, UTF-8, UTF-16, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

[N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers**
> ...
> 11 An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bitfield.
> If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a
> structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains,
> whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is
> implementation-defined. The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to
> low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of the
> addressable storage unit is unspecified.

Your implementation is apparently allocating a 32-bit `unsigned int` to contain the bit field.  Check your compiler documentation to see if there's a way to force it to use a smaller type for bit-fields, although I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: so...essentially my computer is allocating the memory size of an unsigned int to just unsigned? if so...that makes sense, thanks. And im using gcc

Comment: @user2646981, `unsigned int` is the same as `unsigned` which comes from C.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use `unsigned char` or `short` for the struct but there is also alignment issue that.

Comment: which is why i'm trying to define it as a type rather than using existing types

Answer (score 1):

It is guaranteed by the standard for `sizeof(char)` to return `1`.

To your `BIT` structure: It is not possible to define a data type that would require less than 1 byte of memory.

And to the bitfields (`:` specifier), if you really really really have to save some memory in all possible ways, you might be lucky enough to do something like this:

```
typedef struct 
{
    char c1 : 4;
    char c2 : 4;
} MyPackedByte;
```

which would allow you to store two 4-bit values within a single byte, yet behavior of this might be compiler specific and maybe you will have to use some preprocessor directives such as `#pragma pack`

see: [#pragma pack effect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3318410/1168156)

Comment: This is really good! Thanks. When I tried pragma pack(1) and told the main function to return sizeof(BIT)...it returned 1!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a struct if you only need 1 bit?  The smallest unit of storage is a byte (typically 1 char); why not typedef BIT to be a char?

Comment: its just an experiment of curiosity. What if i had a really tiny amount of storage to work it, and all i needed was a boolean value...why waste 8 bits when i only need 1?

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't be able to use sizeof() function for a bitfield. You are the one setting how you "cut" your int, maybe you could store it somewhere if you really need to get size of it later?
Something like 
typedef struct 
{
``unsigned bit : 1, bit2 : 3;

``size_t size_bit1, size_bit2;
}BIT;

void initBIT()
{
`size_bit1 = 1;`
size_bit2 = 3;
}