# Order of data while casting array to struct

Tags: c, arrays, casting, struct

Say i have the following struct:

```
typedef struct MyStruct {

    unsigned short a; /* 16 bit unsigned integer*/
    unsigned short b; /* 16 bit unsigned integer*/
    unsigned long  c; /* 32 bit unsigned integer*/

}MY_STRUCT;
```

And some data array (the content only for demonstration):

```
unsigned short data[] = {0x0011, 0x1100, 0x0001, 0x0FFF };
```

Then i perform the folliwing:

```
MY_STRUCT *ms; 

ms = (MY_STRUCT *) data;

printf("a is: %X\n",(*ms).a);
printf("b is: %X\n",(*ms).b);
printf("c is: %X\n",(*ms).c);
```

I would expect the data to be read sequentially into ms, "left to right", in which case the output to be:

```
a is: 11
b is: 1100
c is: 10FFF
```

However what actually happens is:

```
a is: 11
b is: 1100
c is: FFF0001
```

Why does this happen? What behavior should i expect when casting arrays to structs this way?

Comment: Little endian machines such as x86 store multibyte types in reversed order.

Comment: Note: You're violating [strict aliasing](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html) with that cast. You're fortunate the compiler didn't 32-bit-align the leading members.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the machine you are executing this piece of code has little endian byte ordering. This means that it stores its bytes in reverse order.

The number 0x4A3B2C1D would be stored as 0x1D 0x2C 0x3B 0x4A.

Intel x86 is a little endian architecture.

The reason why your `a` and `b` are correct is because you store a `short` when creating data and then you load the `shorts` again. For c, it is a bit different. You store 2 `shorts`, but then you try to load it as a long. You didn't store the `shorts` as the processor would have stored them if they were to combine as a long so they get reversed.

Answer (score 1):

> What behavior should i expect when casting arrays to structs this way?

The answer is, it depends.  Welcome to the wonderful world of Endian-ness:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

The gist is, you are assuming data is stored in the manner in which you would expect a human to read.  This is big endian.  You're probably on an x86 machine, however, which is little endian.  This means the most significant digits are at the end of the 4 bytes, not at the start.  That's why your 2nd half short is showing up before the first half of your short.

You will get different results on different architectures with this method.

Comment: Outstanding, but x86 machines are **little endian**; not big. And the endianness is traditionally used to describe what is stored *first* (the "last" is a consequence of that). I.e. Little-endian means the *least* significant bytes are stored first; big-endian means the *most* significant bytes are stored first.

Comment: I just realized and edited.  The moral of the story is don't try to answer SO at 2:40AM.

Comment: LOL. that still gives me two hours.

Answer (score 0):

As others have explained, the result depends on endianess. In addition to that, your code is unsafe and invokes undefined behavior. Because there is no guarantee that you can cast from a struct to an array of short.

This is because of data alignment. Many CPUs prefers or demands data bytes to be allocated on even addresses. For example, a 32-bit CPU with such an alignment requirement would want data to be stored at an address which is divisible by 4 (addresses correspond to bytes, 4 bytes = 32 bits).

If the data is not stored on such an even address, it is *misaligned*, which will lead to poor CPU performance on most mainstream 32/64-bit CPUs (86, PowerPC, ARM etc) or possibly that the code can't even execute (rare case, I think some MIPS CPU applies?).

Therefore, during optimization the compiler attempts to store all members of a struct on aligned addresses. This is allowed by the C standard: the compiler is free to add something called *padding bytes*, which is essentially just garbage space allocated between the struct members.

In your example, a compiler for a 32-bit big endian CPU could do something like this:

```
Address         Data
0x00000000      unsigned short a; MS byte
0x00000001      unsigned short b; LS byte
0x00000002      Padding byte
0x00000003      Padding byte
0x00000004      unsigned short b; MS byte
0x00000005      unsigned short b; LS byte
0x00000006      Padding byte
0x00000007      Padding byte
0x00000008      unsigned long  c; MS byte
0x00000009      unsigned long  c; 
0x0000000A      unsigned long  c; 
0x0000000B      unsigned long  c; LS byte
```

As you can see, trying to interpret this memory chunk as an array of `short` would give you problems, since you would end up with padding bytes in the middle of the array.

So formally, casting between structs and arrays of data is undefined behavior and bad practice. But there are various non-standard extensions that will allow you to disable struct padding, the most common is [`#pragma pack`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318410/pragma-pack-effect). If you invoke such a non-standard compiler setting, then your code would work in practice.

Comment: If you work on 8-bit or 16-bit CPUs however, they likely don't have alignment requirements and therefore no struct padding. But the C standard is generic and independent of CPU type.