# JNI Structure Alignment

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, jna

I'm calling a DLL compiled with the VisualStudio 2005 with the "#pragma pack(1)" setting. So the structure alligment (SA) is without padding for fast data access [1].
I think the JVM is compiled with normal structure alligment [2].

So I want to know what are my options?
The call to the dll(I'm not in Codecontrol) is going through a wrapper dll (I'm in Codecontrol).

1. Can I call out of the Wrapper a dll with another SA setting? So that the Wrapper-Dll, which is called from Java uses the normal SA setting and calls a dll which is compiled with #pragma pack(1) set.
2. Is it possible to do a setting in JNI to call dlls with #pragma pack(1) set?
3. I also could use JNA. Is there a possibility to do such an setup.

[1] [#pragma pack effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318410/pragma-pack-effect)

[2] http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t128433-jni-with-1-byte-alignment-crashes-jvm.html

Comment: If the .h describing the structure in the VS2005 dll is pragma pack(1), so long as your .h describing the structure is as well, I don't see what the issue is.  Can you add code indicating how this is a JVM/JNI issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#pragma pack` affects how the compiler treats code until it sees another `#pragma pack` or a `#pragma pop`, so you can have as many different structures with different alignment as you need.  As long as you don't have a `pack` setting when you include `jni.h` you should be fine.  The easiest way to ensure that is to include the JNI headers before you include any of your structure definitions with custom alignment.

JNA explicitly provides a structure alignment of "none" which maps to `#pragma pack(1)`, and it may be set for an entire library (i.e. all structures defined within that library interface):

```
interface MyLibrary extends Library {
    int STRUCTURE_ALIGNMENT = Structure.ALIGN_NONE;
}
```

Or you can set it for an individual structure:

```
class MyStructure extends Structure {
    public MyStructure() {
        super(ALIGN_NONE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The #pragma pack directive is intended to locally "overwrite" the /Zp compiler option.
It means that a Dll compiled with some /Zp[n] option can still use structure requiring a different aligment, provided that the structure declarations are enclosed with #pragma pack.

Example:

One Header

```
// lib.h, structure must be 1 byte aligned
struct lib {
    char ch;
    void * p;
};
```

Source using the lib, compiled with /Zp4

```
// user.cpp
#pragma pack(push, 1) // force 1 byte for the header, save current value
#include "lib.h"
#pragma pack(pop)    // restore saved structure aligment
```