# Pragma Pack used C library causing the jvm to crash

Tags: java, c, memory-management, jvm, jna

I used a C library in my Java code using JNA. I have these C structures of whose members I need to print in Java. Because of the memory alignment and padding the size was differing from what I was actually expecting. Therefore I used pragma pack and this is how the structures look like now.

```
#define PACK( __Declaration__ ) __pragma( pack(push, 1) ) __Declaration__ __pragma( pack(pop) )

PACK(
typedef struct 
{
    size_t size;
    uint8_t bytes[48];
} ipj_tid_t);


PACK(
typedef struct 
{
    bool has_epc; //1
    ipj_epc_t epc; //64+8
    bool has_tid; //1
    ipj_tid_t tid; //48+8
    bool has_pc; //1
    uint32_t pc; //4
    bool has_xpc; //1
    uint32_t xpc; //4
    bool has_crc; //1
    uint32_t crc; //4
    bool has_timestamp; //1
    uint64_t timestamp; //8
    bool has_rssi; //1
    int32_t rssi; //4
    bool has_phase; //1
    int32_t phase; //4
    bool has_channel; //1
    uint32_t channel; //4
    bool has_antenna; //1
    uint32_t antenna; //4
} ipj_tag); //total size= 174


PACK(
typedef struct 
{
    bool has_error;
    ipj_error error;
    bool has_test_id;
    uint32_t test_id;
    bool has_result_1;
    uint32_t result_1;
    bool has_result_2;
    uint32_t result_2;
    bool has_result_3;
    uint32_t result_3;
    size_t data_count;
    uint32_t data[16];
    bool has_timestamp;
    uint64_t timestamp;
    size_t lt_buffer_count;
    uint32_t lt_buffer[21];
} ipj_test_report);


PACK(
typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    uint8_t bytes[64];
} ipj_tag_operation_data_t);


PACK(
typedef  struct
{
    bool has_error;  //1
    ipj_error error; //4
    bool has_tag; //1
    ipj_tag tag; //174
    bool has_tag_operation_type; //1
    ipj_tag_operation_type tag_operation_type; //4
    bool has_tag_operation_data; //1
    ipj_tag_operation_data_t tag_operation_data; //72
    bool has_retries; //1
    uint32_t retries; //4
    bool has_diagnostic; //1
    uint32_t diagnostic; //4
    bool has_timestamp; //1
    uint64_t timestamp; //8
    size_t lt_buffer_count; //8
    uint32_t lt_buffer[30]; //120
} ipj_tag_operation_report); //405
```

When I run the code from Visual Studio, I am not getting any errors, exceptions or crashes from it. But when I call this from Java, the jvm is crashing. Why is this happening? There are other structures in the C code too which are not packed. Could it be a reason? Please advice.

The structures I have shown above are used in C. What is returned from the C code is this structure after all the processing.

```
#define RX_MAX_SIZE     405
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct _report
{
    ipj_report_id report_id;
    uint32_t data_size;
    uint32_t data[RX_MAX_SIZE];
 } report;
 #pragma pack(pop)
```

The equivalent JNA structure that has been used is as follows.

```
public class _report extends Structure {

    public static class ByValue extends _report implements Structure.ByValue {

    }

    public _report() {
        super();
        setAlignType(ALIGN_NONE);
    }

    public _ipj_report_id reportid;
    public int data_size;
    public int[] data = new int[405]; 

    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("reportid", "data_size", "data");
    }

}

public class _ipj_report_id extends Structure {

    public int ipj_report_id;

    public _ipj_report_id() {
        super();
        setAlignType(ALIGN_NONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("ipj_report_id");
    }

}
```

Below is the structure I get when debugging the JNA code.

```
    _report$ByValue(auto-allocated@0x18918cc0 (1628 bytes)) {
   _ipj_report_id reportid@0=_ipj_report_id(allocated@0x18918cc0 (4 bytes) (shared from auto-allocated@0x18918cc0 (1628 bytes))) {
    int ipj_report_id@0=0
   }
   int data_size@4=195
   int data[405]@8=[I@78bb0ecb
 }
```

Below is how I call this method in JNA.

```
 rfidlib rlib = (rfidlib) Native.loadLibrary("rfidlib", rfidlib.class);
_report.ByValue report = new _report.ByValue();
 report = rlib.get_next_reports();
```

Comment: Can you show us any error output you might have?  One possibility is the version of the JVM you are using (e.g. 32 versus 64 bit).

Comment: It doesn't show any errors. I do get the output printed on the console. Then suddenly JVM crashes. When I remove the packing code it works fine. Its a 64bit JVM and 64 bit dll. Please advice.

Comment: [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856048/jni-structure-alignment) may help.

Comment: I tried the setAlignmentType to No alignment in my structure. Still no help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JNA structure mapping with no alignment and padding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944616/jna-structure-mapping-with-no-alignment-and-padding)

Comment: @technomage I asked that question too. No answer yet for it :(

Comment: @technomage I have edited the question mate. Could you please help me out with this.

Comment: 1628 is exactly the size I would expect for no alignment/packing for the `_report` struct.  What exactly doesn't match up?

Comment: If your `get_reports()` function returns a `struct` (as opposed to `struct*`), you need to declare it in JNA as returning `_report.ByValue`, otherwise the results will be unpredictable.  Please include _all_ relevant native code _and_ the corresponding JNA mappings you're using.

Answer (score 0):

JNA assumes default structure layout for the current target platform (in this case, the MS compiler).

You can print the layout of the JNA-generated memory layout by calling `Structure.toString()` after invoking the JVM with `-Djna.dump_memory=true`.

You can then compare your desired structure layout with the actual layout generated by JNA to look for differences.  If you generically use `boolean` in your Java structure, the default is to allocate a native `int`, so if that's not the same size as your native `bool`, you need to either use `byte` on the Java side or explicitly supply a `TypeMapper` to your `Structure` to indicate that `boolean` should be converted to a size compatible with native `bool` (note that the size of native `bool` is not defined by the C standard).

I would recommend *not* using `#pragma pack` in your code unless you explicitly need it.

Please update your question with your Java `Structure` implementation and its debug output.

Comment: I will check this on monday and let you know the output. i dont have the device now to run the program :(

Comment: I have edited the question with required info mate. Could you please help me out with this.