# c++ and opencv get and set pixel color to Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, pixel, mat

I'm trying to set a new color value to some pixel into a cv::Mat image my code is below:

```
    Mat image = img;
    for(int y=0;y<img.rows;y++)
    {
        for(int x=0;x<img.cols;x++)
        {
        Vec3b color = image.at<Vec3b>(Point(x,y));
        if(color[0] > 150 && color[1] > 150 && color[2] > 150)
        {
            color[0] = 0;
            color[1] = 0;
            color[2] = 0;
            cout << "Pixel >200 :" << x << "," << y << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            color.val[0] = 255;
            color.val[1] = 255;
            color.val[2] = 255;
        }
    }
    imwrite("../images/imgopti"+to_string(i)+".tiff",image);
```

It seems to get the good pixel in output (with cout) however in the output image (with imwrite) the pixel concerned aren't modified. I have already tried using color.val[0].. I still can't figure out why the pixel colors in the output image dont change.
thanks

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You did everything except copying the new pixel value back to the image.

This line takes a copy of the pixel into a local variable:

```
Vec3b color = image.at<Vec3b>(Point(x,y));
```

So, after changing `color` as you require, just set it back like this:

```
image.at<Vec3b>(Point(x,y)) = color;
```

So, in full, something like this:

```
Mat image = img;
for(int y=0;y<img.rows;y++)
{
    for(int x=0;x<img.cols;x++)
    {
        // get pixel
        Vec3b & color = image.at<Vec3b>(y,x);

        // ... do something to the color ....
        color[0] = 13;
        color[1] = 13;
        color[2] = 13;

        // set pixel
        //image.at<Vec3b>(Point(x,y)) = color;
        //if you copy value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

just use a reference:

```
Vec3b & color = image.at<Vec3b>(y,x);
color[2] = 13;
```

Comment: because the problem was about a color Mat. in the uchar case, ofc. use `uchar& c = image.at<uchar>(y,x)`

Answer (score 17):

I would not use .at for performance reasons.

Define a struct:

```
//#pragma pack(push, 2) //not useful (see comments below)
struct BGR {
    uchar blue;
    uchar green;
    uchar red;  };
```

And then use it like this on your cv::Mat image:

```
BGR& bgr = image.ptr<BGR>(y)[x];
```

image.ptr(y) gives you a pointer to the scanline y. And iterate through the pixels with loops of x and y

Comment: What is the sense of setting `pack` value to 2 if `sizeof(uchar)` is 1?

Comment: The compiler will add padding Bytes to a struct. The setting of pack changes those paddings so that the data is aligned in another way.Edit: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318410/pragma-pack-effect

Comment: `pragma` has no effect on a struct made solely from `uchar`s. Read a nice explanation [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/compbgpl/v9v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp9.bg.doc/compiler_ref/pragma_pack.htm) for details.

Comment: Thx good link. Seem the pragma really is useless in this case :) thx!

Comment: You're welcome :) And nice answer: less magic, more efficient.

Comment: You actually want to call this struct BGR, or similiar, since by default OpenCV stores the bands in BGR format.

Comment: Yes, the struct-name is in the wrong order. No biggy in my opinion though... but yes, you are correct :)

Answer (score -1):

if image is 3 channel:

```
imageData.at<cv::Vec3b>(ptX,ptY)=cv::Vec3b(0,0,255);
```

It shows red color pixel update B=0,G=0,R=255