# Convert pixel color in image using openCV

Tags: java, android, opencv

So what i'm basically trying to do is converting the pixel in image to the color i want, i'm not finding anything in openCV for java , the only way i come up with is this :

```
     for (int i = 0; i < image.cols(); i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < image.rows(); j++) {

     double[] data = image.get(i, j);
     data[0] = 255;
     data[1] = 255;
     data[2] = 255;
     image.put(i, j, data);
     }
     }
     Utils.matToBitmap(image, bmp);
     return bmp;;
```

trying to imtate this [c++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23002034/4196092) in java, but its not working

Comment: is this c++ or java?

Comment: no this is java and i'm trying to imitate the c++ code

Comment: do not try to imitate c++ code. use higher level functions, like `image.setTo(Scalar.all(255))`

Comment: if you **ever** try to access pixels like that from java - you're doing it wrong.

Comment: thanks i found out why it was not working with me, is should use 
 ` for (int i = 0; i < image.height(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < image.width(); j++) { `
but i'm gonna try ` image.setTo(Scalar.all(255)) ` , because my code is very slow , thanks again

Answer (score 0):

ok found out why it is not working, i should have write :

```
for (int i = 0; i < image.height(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < image.width(); j++) {
```

instead of :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < image.cols(); i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < image.rows(); j++) {
```