# OpenCV Processing - Edge detection and Cropping

Tags: c++, opencv, crop, edge-detection, image-preprocessing

How do i remove the irregular white pixels from the preprocessed image.

i have tried doing erosion and that would make all pixels black.

After Preprocessing:

[image]

Requirement:

[image]

My Code:

```
Mat  img, edges, erode, blurred, element;
element = getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(7, 7), cv::Point(-1,-1) ); 

img = imread("img1925.jpeg");    //  read the image
cv::Canny(img, edges, 30, 255, 3);    // detect the edges with threshold limit

//    cv::erode(edges, erode, element);

GaussianBlur(edges, blurred, cv::Size(7, 7), 0);    // blurring

//    Rect ROI = boundingRect(blurred);       // draw rect for ROI
//    Mat src = thresh(ROI);

namedWindow("image", WINDOW_NORMAL);
imshow("image", blurred);
waitKey(0);
return 0;
```

Looking for suggestions!

Comment: You can easily use a function which makes pixels any value which you want. If you have a certain interval values of RGB, you can change any pixel you want: 
       openCvImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0]=0; (i and j are the coordinates, [0] represents first layer, 0 is the value you assigned. Related topic:<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001512/c-and-opencv-get-and-set-pixel-color-to-mat>

Comment: Unfortunately, I have lot of images and I am not sure where the irregular pixels are! So that option doesn't work.

Comment: What do u mean exactly by saying "irregular pixels"

Comment: irregularities in the image is what I mean when i tell irregular pixels. My roi might be located on the top and irregularities can be present at the bottom. So using the pointers to alter will work on 1-2 images not on thousands of images :(

Comment: After preprocessing step, you can check the density of irregular pixels, to locate your roi correctly.

Comment: This sounds like a solution. I would look into this. I would appreciate if you could throw some light too!

Comment: But there are some issues u ll probably have problem. 1- Gaussian Blur doesnt always give the results you need, 2- You can check the pixel values of your image using the method I mentioned in first comment of me. 3- You can see where the white pixels are majority and locate your rectangle there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by removing the irregular white pixels from the preprocessed image but if your goal is to extract a ROI of the object then here's an approach:

- Convert image to grayscale and Gaussian blur to smooth image
- Adaptive threshold to obtain a binary image
- Find contours and filter using contour area
- Extract the largest contour in the image and crop the ROI

---

Here's the result

[image]

If you cropped the ROI on the thresholded image, here's the result

[image]

I implemented it in Python but you can follow the same steps in C++

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7,7), 0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,3)

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    break

cv2.imwrite('ROI.png', ROI)
cv2.waitKey()
```