# Two GCC compiles for same input, two different codes generated (second one wrong)

Tags: c++, gcc

I am having a strange issue with GCC (4.6.4, Ubuntu 12.04) sometimes, I am using it to compile a huge project (hundreds of files and hundreds of thousands of lines of code), but I recently spotted something. After certain compiles (seems to happen randomly), I get a specific piece of code compiled differently and erroneously, causing undefined behavior in my code:

```
class someDerivedClass : public someBaseClass
{
    public:
        struct anotherDerived : public anoterBaseClass
        {
            void SomeMethod()
            {
                someMember->someSetter(2);
            }
        }
}
```

Where "someSetter" is defined as:

```
void someSetter(varType varName) { someOtherMember = varName; }
```

Normally, SomeMethod() gets compiled to:

```
00000000019fd910  mov 0x20(%rdi),%rax 
00000000019fd914  movl $0x2,0x278c(%rax) 
00000000019fd91e  retq
```

But sometimes it gets (wrongfully) compiled to:

```
000000000196e4ee  mov 0x20(%rdi),%rax 
000000000196e4f2  movl $0x2,0x27d4(%rax) 
000000000196e4fc  retq
```

The setter seems to get inlined, probably because of compile flags -O2:

```
-std=c++11 -m64 -O2 -ggdb3 -pipe -Wliteral-suffix -fpermissive -fno-fast-math -fno-strength-reduce -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -fno-strict-aliasing
```

but that's not the issue. The real issue is the offset of the member **someOtherMember**, **0x278c** is correct (first case) but **0x27d4** is incorrect (second case) and this obviously ends up modifying a totally different member of the class. Why is this happening? What am I missing? (also, I don't know what other relevant info I can post, so ask). Please keep in mind that this happens when compiling the project again (either full recompile or just compiling modified files only), **without** modifying the affected file (or files with the used classes). For example, just adding a simple printf() somewhere in a totally unrelated file might trigger this behavior or make it go away when it happens.
Should I simply blame this on the -O2? I can't reproduce it without optimization flag because this happens totally random.
I am using **make -j 8**, this happens even after cleaning build folder, but doesn't necessarily happen only after doing that

Comment: You may have an undefined behavior nearby.

Comment: This smells like you're violating the one definition rule to me but I can't tell you how, or in what specific way it causes your problem.

Comment: Too difficult for guessing. We'll likely need a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @AndyG: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce this with a simple test project, that's why I'm open to guessing. iKiWiXz care to elaborate?

Comment: I'd be tempted to look at the build system. Are some dependencies not getting picked up? Are you running a parallel build (eg. `make -j 4`)? Does this ever happen after a `make clean`? etc...

Comment: @galik Added requested info: yes I am using parallel build (make -j 8), yes it does happen after clean. Regarding dependencies, not sure how I can answer to that since this happens when simply modifying random file in project, without affecting dependecies OR the actual file containing problematic code

Comment: My guess is that your .h gets included in several .cpp, but in some of them there's something that changes the default class layout (#pragma pack or similar, or you have a member of a type defined differently), so different versions of the methods get generated, from which the linker picks one more or less at random.

Answer (score 5):

As stated in the comments, you probably have something that conditions the definition of your class differently in the various `.cpp`, for example a `#pragma pack` or something like that before the inclusion of your `.h`; when the linker has to choose, it may choose non-deterministically (since it expects all the definitions to be the same).

To narrow your search for the root of the problem, I would do something like this:

1. compile your whole project with debug symbols (`-g`);
2. use `gdb` to determine what is the offset of the "problematic" field according to each module
3. once you find where you have different values, you may use `gcc -E` to expand all the preprocessor stuff and look for your problem.

As an aid for step 2, you can use this bash one-liner (to be run in the directory where are the object files):

```
for i in ./*.o; do echo -n "$i: "; gdb -batch -q "$i" -ex "print &((YourClass*)0)->yourField"; done
```

Comment: I'm having an issue with this. For all except one .o files I get "No symbol "SomeClass" in current context.", only in SomeClass.cpp.o I get the expected result, although SomeClass.h (which contains the definition of my problematic class) is included in many other .cpp files. Don't know if it's worth mentioning but I'm using precompiled headers

Comment: Precompiled headers do add another dimension to the problem, but since I never used them I can't tell you for sure how they may affect this test; maybe you could try to build without the PCH and see what happens?

Comment: Unfortunately project can't be compiled without PCH currently, requires lot of changes. But I do have various #pragma packs, I will try removing them since it's the faster course of action

Comment: Kind of a late reply, but issue is still there, even with GCC 6.2.0. I also removed all the `#pragma pack`, didn't help. Any other thoughts?