# Packing nested structs in C++

Tags: c++, struct, size, packing

Using Visual Studio 2017, the following gives...

```
struct AAA // 15 bytes
{
    double d;
    short s;
    char a1;
    char a2;
    char a3;
    char s4;
    char s5;
};

struct BBB
{
    AAA d;
    char a4;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(AAA) << "\n"; // gives 16
    std::cout << sizeof(BBB) << "\n"; // gives 24
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The Question is... how do I get sizeof(BBB) to be 16.

Comment: Look up `#pragma pack` and maybe related questions if that alone doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `#pragma pack(push, 1)` or `#pragma pack(1)` to enforce compiler not to line up structure members on 2 byte or 4 byte boundaries which makes it *easier and faster for the processor to handle*. So the structure contains **secret padding bytes** to make this happen. But this increases memory usage because of padding.

Its a precise explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318410/pragma-pack-effect)

Comment: the thing is that `char a4` fits exactly to the last padding byte, but compilers aren't allowed to pack it into that place. It looks like the OP wants that behavior without packing. See [Standard-layout and tail padding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53837373/995714)

Answer (score 0):

```
struct AAA // 15 bytes
{
    double d;
    short s;
    char a1;
    char a2;
    char a3;
    char s4;
    char s5;
};

#pragma pack(1)

struct BBB
{
    AAA d;
    char a4;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(AAA) << "\n"; // gives 16
    std::cout << sizeof(BBB) << "\n"; // gives 17
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code :

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct AAA // 15 bytes
{
    double d;
    short s;
    char a1;
    char a2;
    char a3;
    char s4;
    char s5;
};

#pragma pack(1)
struct BBB
{
    AAA d;
    char a4;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{        
    std::cout << sizeof(AAA) << "\n"; // gives 15
    std::cout << sizeof(BBB) << "\n"; // gives 16
    getchar();


    return 0;
}
```

The result will be :

```
15
16
```

`structs`, and `unions` have stricter alignment requirements that ensure consistent aggregate and `union` storage and data retrieval. There is suggested alignment for the scalar members of `unions` and `structures`.
Structure size must be an integral multiple of its alignment, which may require padding after the last member.

`#pragma pack` statement change the alignment of a `structure`.

Answer (score -1):

using

```
#pragma pack(1)
```

will results into sizeof(AAA) to be 15 and sizeof(BBB) to be 16.