# Inlining struct member

Tags: c++, struct

I have a struct `Foo` which contains a nested struct `Bar`. These structs only contain POD types. My problem is that the size of `Foo` is larger than it would have been if I copied all the members of `Bar`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Bar {
    double a;
    long long b;
    int c;
};

struct Foo {
    Bar b;
    int d;
};

struct Foo2 {
    double a;
    long long b;
    int c;
    int d;
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << sizeof(Foo) << std::endl;
  std::cout << sizeof(Bar) << std::endl;
  std::cout << sizeof(Foo2) << std::endl;
}
```

> 32
> 24
> 24

[Demo](http://cpp.sh/9i2uz)

I understand that this is happening because `Bar` gets padded to 24 bytes so `Foo` adds a single int which then gets padded to 32 bytes. I don't want to mark `Bar` or `Foo` as packed. I was wondering if there is any way to tell the compiler to not store `Bar` as a struct but to just include its members? Something like:

```
struct Foo {
    inline Bar b; // Keyword inline doesn't work here.
    int d;
};
```

Comment: `I don't want to mark Bar or Foo as packed.` Why not?

Comment: @eerorika possible degrade in performance?

Comment: Several reasons: 1. It makes the code less readable 2. It might degrade performance 3. Bar is from an external library so I can't modify it. 4. Not sure how portable it is.

Comment: @TonyTannous OP is trying to only overlap members with padding, not to misalign the members.

Comment: Could you explain why this is a problem in your case. Padding could vary depening on which compiler, version and compiler flags are used and how the member itself are used. So you actually cannot guarantee that `Foo2` and `Foo` have the same aligment.

Comment: [Standard-layout and tail padding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53837373/995714), [Packing nested structs in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44023837/995714), [When extending a padded struct, why can't extra fields be placed in the tail padding?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24110347/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We must allow the member to be a potentially-overlapping subobject. There are two ways: 1. Instead of using a member, inherit from `Bar` or 2. Use the attribute `[[no_unique_address]]` (C++20).

Technically, being potentially-overlapping is sufficient to allow the compiler to re-use the padding. However, unfortunately being able to reuse the padding doesn't guarantee the re-use and in practice, certain language implementations do not re-use padding of trivially copyable standard layout types. We can work around this by making the sub object non-trivially-copyable or non-standard-layout.

> I can't modify [Bar]

Then making it non-trivially-copyable-standard-layout type won't be possible, and therefore certain language implementations won't reuse the padding.

Comment: I already tried inheritance and it doesn't change the outcome. https://godbolt.org/z/eTY3rz

Comment: @TonyTannous You forgot the part of making Bar a  non-trivially-copyable-standard-layout type.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61557807/580083, https://stackoverflow.com/q/52818411/580083.