# C++ Class packing / member alignment

Tags: c++, class, memory-alignment, packing

I know structure packing is a common thing in C++ programming (at least on low memory systems). But what about classes.
I know it works because I tried it

```
#include <iostream>

#pragma pack(push, 1)
class Test_Packed {
    uint8_t t;
    uint32_t test;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

class Test_Unpacked {
    uint8_t t;
    uint32_t test;
};

int main() {
    std::cout<<sizeof(Test_Packed) << " / " << sizeof(Test_Unpacked)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Which correctly outputs "5 / 8".

Can I assume this to be the case on all conforming Compilers, or is this implementation defined?

I know that adding virtual members (and thus needing a vtable) will add additional data in the front. What can be other reasons for this to fail?

Can this cause any problems except for poor performance on some platforms?

Comment: It's implementation defined.

Comment: This question itself is a great demo of proper `#pragma pack` usage and syntax. Just what I was looking for on how to use `#pragma pack`!

Comment: Keep in mind, in C++, a `struct` is just a class where all members default to `public` if not otherwise specified, and a `class` is just a class/struct where all members default to `private` unless otherwise specified, so it seems to me that more narrowly packing just the desired members within a class or struct, rather than the entire class or struct as you have done, would affect a class or struct identically.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318410/pragma-pack-effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [`#pragma`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/impl) states:

> Implementation defined behavior is controlled by `#pragma` directive.

So the effect, if any, of `#pragma pack(push, 1)` and `#pragma pack(pop)`
is **completely** "implementation defined."