# Can you determine the size of all class types in the same way?

Tags: c++

Can you determine the size of class types, except unions, in somewhat the same way, like calculating the sum of all data members?

I know that for classes, there probably is a little bit more to consider when determining the size, but is calculating the sum of all data members the right way to find the **minimum size** of all class types, except unions?

Comment: You mean sizeof? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

Comment: Just calculating the sum of sizes of members ignores things like *alignment* and *padding*. Use `sizeof`.

Comment: @Matzi I know about sizeof, but it is more about how the size is determined.. like for a class, it is at least the sum of its data members.. but is this also valid for structs etc.?

Comment: `class`es and `struct`s are *the same thing* - they only differ in their default access specifier and default inheritance type - nothing else.

Answer (score 4):

There is this [useful utility](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) called `sizeof`. It just gives you the compile time size of the type or expression you pass in.

Let the compiler handle it for you. And the expression is not even evaluated, and the result can be used in `constexpr` environment. Also it handles platform specific differences.

```
class Example {
  int member;
  const char* otherMember;
};

const int size = sizeof(Example);
```

To answer the actual question:

> Can you determine the size of class types, except unions, in somewhat
>   the same way... ?

The answer is yes, you can use `sizeof`, and

> ...like calculating the sum of all data members?

No it might not be the same. You can do that, but it can differ a lot from the real size. Also some basic types can have different sizes on some platforms, you probably better off using sizeof for them as well, and in that case you can just do this for the whole class.

> is calculating the sum of all data members the **right way** to find the
>   minimum size of all class types, except unions?

It will be a conservative estimation which might be less than the real size. So it is not the **right way**. Hard to see why it would be any use if you can have the real thing for literally no cost. Also it works on unions, pointers, expressions. And portable.

Comment: That answers, what should be used instead of summing up manually, but not if summing up the data members gives you the _minimum size_.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you want to make a **lower bound** for a class's size, then the summed sizeof its members do it.

A class without virtual functions usually have the sum of its members, plus padding between members. Padding is usually put between members because of alignment.

A class with virtual functions usually have a hidden `sizeof(void*)`-sized member in it (a pointer to the virtual table).

A class with virtual inheritance usually can have even more hidden things.

So, for example, this class usually have a sizeof 8 (where `sizeof(int)` is 4):

```
struct Foo {
    char c; // there is a 3-byte padding between c and i, because i
    int i;  // is need a 4-aligned address
};
```

**Note**: these things are not specified in the standard, any compiler implementation may work differently. If you need the authoritative size of a class, use `sizeof`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to determine the size of an object in C++ is to use the sizeof operator.

From a more theoretical point yes, adding up the sizes of the members will tell you the size of the class. For unions it is more or less the same. Get the object size for each alternative. Then largest wins.

Comment: It gets a little more complex than this once virtual functions get involved, even more so with virtual inheritance. Although the size will be predictable for a particular platform/ABI, the exact algorithm can vary substantially.

Comment: "adding up the sizes of the members will tell you the size of the class" - *No, it will not*. You are ignoring padding and allignment of members if you just do that. Consider `struct s { char c; int i; };` - naively adding the size of members will (usually) give you 5, but the real size (as reported by `sizeof`) will (usually) be 8.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you determine the size of class types, except unions, in somewhat the same way, like calculating the sum of all data members?

No, you can't.

> I know that for classes, there probably are a little bit more to consider when determining the size ...

Yes, there are more things to consider. Alignment of data members and padding 1st of all.

Also involving virtual polymorphism may influence the size of a class, let's see a little example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base1 {
public:
    void foo() {}
};

class Derived1 : public Base1 {
    int i;
public:
    void foo() {}
};

class Base2 {
public:
     virtual ~Base2() {}
     virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Derived2 : public Base2 {
    int i;
public:
     virtual ~Derived2() {}
     virtual void foo() {}
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "Size Derived1: " << sizeof(Derived1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Size Derived2: " << sizeof(Derived2) << std::endl;
}
```

output is

```
Size Derived1: 4
Size Derived2: 16
```

(See it live [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f8a64a35299b0c1))

> ... but is calculating the sum of all data members the right way to find the minimum size of all class types, except unions?

Speaking for the *absolute minimum size* yes. But even if you put compiler pragmas like [`#pragma pack(1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318410/pragma-pack-effect) to eliminate the alignments and paddings, just summing up the data members won't give you the *minimum size* for other considerations like virtual polymorphism.