# Can I force a C++ class to compile using the minimum amount of space?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, memory-optimization

I have a class that I will literally instantiate billions of.  I did my best to put as little data as possible in it, and I got it down to 10 bytes when compiled for an x64 architecture: an `unsigned short int` and a `size_t`.  When I mouse over `sizeof(myclass)` (in VS), however, it reports 16 bytes.  If I comment out either of the fields, the size of the class is what you'd expect, 10 bytes and 2 bytes respectively.

Is there a way to instruct the compiler to use only 10 bytes for my class?

Comment: Try `#pragma pack`

Comment: Thanks!  Throw `#pragma pack(2)` in an answer, and I'll mark it as the best answer.

Comment: @dfoverdx use `pack(1)` instead of 2

Comment: @RemyLebeau why `pack(1)` when I know my object is an even number of bytes?

Comment: @dfoverdx if someday you decide to add a 1-byte `char` or `bool` member, `pack(2)` won't produce the smallest size possible, there will be 1 byte of padding. If you want the smallest size possible, use the smallest alignment possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#pragma pack` can make your structures smaller. On the other hand, it can make retrieving the member data slower, since the alignment of the bytes is not guaranteed. As a result the compiler will need extra instructions to fetch the data from different memory locations. For more info, this link has an excellent post: [#pragma pack effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318410/pragma-pack-effect)