# Effectively get the most significant byte of mpz_t struct

Tags: c++, gmp

I wasn't able to find how `gmpxx` stores the `mpz_t` structs under the hood. Thus the only way to get the most significant byte of a number stored as `mpz_t` is using the `mpz_get_str` method, but I would expect it to be very slow.

Do you know of a more effective (and simple) way of doing this?

I mean the 'most significant byte' of the number (which is in my case saved as `mpz_t`) in binary. I.e. for 12345 (10) = 11000000111001 (2) it would be 11000000, no matter `gmpxx` actually stores it.

Comment: What's a "_most significant byte_" of a structure?

Comment: @Ron The MSB is the byte that represents the highest part of a number stored in multiple bytes. The order of these bytes depends on CPU architecture (endianess).

Comment: @user0042 that's for a single number. What does MSB mean in the context of a struct?

Comment: @Kevin Good point.

Comment: Thanks, I clarified it. I don't think the architecture matters. The most significant byte of "123456" is always the same - for big endian the leftmost, for little endian the rightmost, which are equal.

Comment: @Kevin there is no meaning in context of structs in general, but the MSB of `mpz_t` struct would presumably be the the MSB of the most significant *limb* pointed by the struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two functions to look at here:
`size_t mpz_sizeinbase(mpz_t op, int base)`: this returns the length in a base, and for `base=2`, it gives the number of bits.
`void mpz_tdiv_r_2exp (mpz_t r, const mpz_t n, mp_bitcnt_t b)`: this is equivalent to `r = n >> b;`. 
Combined, the operation you are looking for is to bit-shift right exactly `sizeinbase-8`times:

```
size_t bit_length = mpz_sizeinbase(number, 2);
mpz_tdiv_r_2exp(last_byte, number, bit_length-8);
```

As a sidenote, the mpz_t struct is stored in "limbs", which are primitives that are chained together. These limbs can have leading 0's to make editing the number easier for small value changes - so accessing them directly is not recommended.

> A limb means the part of a multi-precision number that fits in a single machine word. (We chose this word because a limb of the human body is analogous to a digit, only larger, and containing several digits.) Normally a limb is 32 or 64 bits. The C data type for a limb is mp_limb_t. 
>   ~https://gmplib.org/manual/Nomenclature-and-Types.html#Nomenclature-and-Types

Answer (score -2):

You can create a union without padding (see [#pragma pack effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318410/pragma-pack-effect)) with 2 members: your struct and a byte, then assign a value to your struct, then read the value of the byte. However, I am not sure if it fits to your definition of MSB.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour. Unions cannot be used for type-punning in C++.

Comment: Yes, you are right, however it may be OK in C, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664848/unions-and-type-punning.

Comment: @AndreyBelykh it may not be UB in C, but even in that language there is no such guarantee that the byte member would contain the most significant byte in particular.

Comment: Not sure, it maybe implementation dependent.

Comment: Who cares if C allows it? This question is only tagged `c++`.