# Can the pointer in C++ (windows VC++ compiler) be aligned with __declspec?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

In Linux (gcc) I can align a structure by

```
#ifndef WIN32
    #define ALIGN(size) __attribute__((aligned(size)))
#else
    #define ALIGN(size) __declspec(align(size))
#endif
struct Test {
    float buffer[12];
};
Test ALIGN(16) test;
```

The pointer alignment maybe defined as

```
#ifndef WIN32
    #define ALIGN_PTR(size) __attribute__((align_value(size)))
#endif
Test * ALIGN_PTR(16) pTest;
```

Question:

What is equivalent `__attribute__((align_value(size)))` in windows VC++ compiler?

This question should be no relevant to another solution with #pragma pack, since I think the key point is how to align the memory address that is equivalent to Linux in MSVC, but not align the struct size itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#pragma pack effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318410/pragma-pack-effect)

Comment: I'm not sure. Is #pragma pack equivalent to _declspec(align(size)) in case that  different piece of code uses different alignment size?

Comment: Favor [the standard way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn956970.aspx).  For old MSVC++ versions you can use `__declspec(align(12))`.

Comment: It is OK to align the struct size to 12, but not valid for pointers address. That is why I asked the question posted.

Comment: Well, pTest is certainly aligned to 12.  But what it points to is not since you did not force alignment for the Test type.  Not specific to MSVC++.  You can hack it with `_aligned_malloc()`, in GCC land you'd use `aligned_alloc()`.  operator new can align in C++17.

Comment: It is not bad to use ```aligned_alloc()```. But I'm trying to make a library used in linux to work in windows. That library uses __attribute__((align_value(size))) to align the pointer, so I have to find an equivalent way in MSVC.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there's no MSVC equivalent to `align_value` attribute. Since it's purely an optimization hint, and presumably MSVC doesn't support any optimizations that it might enable, you can simply define `ALIGN_PTR(size)` to nothing under Windows.

Comment: Yes, when I used the same align ```__declspec(align(size))``` or ```alignas(size)``` (suggested by Hans Passant) to the pointer, MSVC told me a warning that it did nothing to ```__declspec(align(size))``` or ```alignas(size)``` So the conclusion is that there is no equivalent ```__attribute__((align_value(size)))``` in MSVC? Thanks.