# C memcpy to struct allocation

Tags: c, memcpy

I wrote a simple program to test copying bytes from a byte buffer to a structure using memcpy. However I am not getting the results expected.

I allocate a buffer of 100 bytes, and set the values 0, 1, 2...99.
I then copy the bytes to a structure that is 16 bytes.

Somewhere byte 0x01 gets lost. I am trying to understand what is happening

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct Test {

    uint8_t a;
    uint16_t b;
    uint32_t c;
    uint64_t d;
    uint8_t e;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    uint8_t buffer[100];
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        buffer[i] = i;
    }

    struct Test test;
    memcpy(&test, buffer, sizeof(struct Test));

    printf("A is %ld and should be %ld\n", test.a, 0x00);
    printf("B is %ld and should be %ld\n", test.b, 0x0201);
    printf("C is %ld and should be %ld\n", test.c, 0x06050403);
    printf("D is %ld and should be %ld\n", test.d, 0x1413121110090807);
    printf("E is %ld and should be %ld\n", test.e, 0x15);
}
```

And I get a result of:

```
A is 0 and should be 0
B is 770 and should be 513
C is 117835012 and should be 100992003
D is 1084818905618843912 and should be 1446519769808832519
E is 16 and should be 21
```

770 (B value) is bytes 0302, not 0201 (int 513)

Comment: You need to read about *padding* in structs.

Comment: Yes, if you output in hexadecimal `%lx` it will be easier to see the effect.

Comment: See also [#pragma pack effect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3318410/555045)

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this is the compiler has added *padding* to your struct in order to ensure that `b` is aligned on a 16-bit boundary.  As such, the second byte is unused.

You'll see a much bigger variation if you start re-ordering your struct.  Similarly, the 32-bit and 64-bit values will want an alignment suitable to their type.  So you can end up with significant "holes" due to padding.  Try it!

Often you will see structures that have `reserved` members (particularly for binary formats), instead of relying on padding.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Rookie mistake.
So im guessing the consesus is dont use memcpy to do this type of operation. Better to manually assign each variable (a = buffer[0], b = buffer[2] << 8 | bufer[1])

Comment: That completely depends on what you're trying to achieve.  It's very common to read and write a struct from/to a buffer with `memcpy`.  But you must be careful when making assumptions _external_ to the execution environment (_e.g._ hard-coding memory contents in code, or reading from a file)

Comment: @user2840470 Not necessarily. A common pratical use of *byte streams* memcopied into structs is when you receive network data and payload of N-th level protocol have to be forwarded to (N+1)-th level protocol (for example, IP packet payload is forwarded to TCP). In this cases it's just a design matter: struct are designed to be *packed-data friendly*, and PACK/UNPACK macros are always present in porting layers to manage special cases. So the question is: can your struct be changed in order to be *packed-data friendly*? :) (BTW: +1 for both Q&A. Interesting topic)

Comment: @Cubo78 That makes sense now why I see structs laid out in certain ways. I can definitely change the order of my struct to better match word boundaries. Thanks for explaining more!