# Use of #pragma section in C

Tags: c, pragma

What is the use of

```
          #pragma section
```

directive in C language ?

Comment: Have not you searched before posting it here? please have a look [How to ask on SO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ever tried googling it ?

Comment: always remember to RTM :) http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232785/use-of-pragma-in-c

Answer (score 1):

This #pragma directive allows a directive to be defined. Its effects are implementation-defined. If the pragma is not supported, then it is ignored.

Syntax:

```
#pragma directive
```

#elif directive creates conditional compiling parameters that control the compiling of the source code.
Syntax:

```
#if constant_expression
#elif constant_expression
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

`#pragma` C standard for providing additional information to the compiler
`#elif` is else if precompiler directive such as

```
 #if X == 1
     ...
 #elif X == 2
     ...
 #else 
    ....
 #endif
```