# Preprocessor #pragma related in C and C++

Tags: pragma

I have been observing in some of the headers the use of pragma. But really not sure proper usage of it. Help in this really appreciated

```
#pragma once
#pragma warning ( disable : 4251 )
#pragma warning ( pop )
#pragma warning ( push )
#pragma comment(lib, "dbghelp")
#pragma warn -ccc 
#pragma warn -aus 
#pragma warn -csu 
#pragma warn -spa
pragma pack(push,8)
__cplusplus
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the following for general use of `#pragma` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232785/use-of-pragma-in-c

Comment: The specific use will depend upon your compiler. For GCC the documentation is available at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html

Comment: Or here for MSVC: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805.aspx

Answer (score -1):

The preprocessor #pragma is basically used to change the execution order of the program that is a normal c/c++ program starts from main() and exits from main() but   #pragma allows that to be changed.

the #pragma is divided as follows:-

**#pragma startup < function name without brackets >:-**

> changes the start function that means this function will run before execution of  main()
>
> ```
> #include...
>  void fun1();
>  void fun2();
>  #pragma startup fun1
>  #pragma exit fun2
>  int main()
> {
> ...
> }
> ```

**#pragma exit < function name without brackets >:-**

> changes the exit function that means this function will run after execution of main()
>
> ```
> #include...
>  void fun1();
>  void fun2();
>  #pragma startup fun1
>  #pragma exit fun2
>  int main()
> {
> ...
> }
> ```

**#pragma warn < -type of warning > :-**

> this directive tells the compiler whether or not we want to suppress a specific warning.
>
> ```
> #include...
>   #pragma warn -rvl // return value
>   #pragma warn -par // parameter not used
>   #pragma warn -rch // unreachable code
>
>  void fun(int n)
>   {
>    ...
>      //Do something
>   } 
>
> int main()
>  {
>  ...
>  // Do something
>  fun(); // parameter not used warning suppressed.
> }
> ```

There are many other pragma directives and you can easily find them just by doing an in-depth and proper search on google.

Comment: vote up and accept the answer if you feel satisfied.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all! The OP asked about `#pragma once`, `#pragma warning`, `#pragma comment`, `#pragma warn` and `pragma pack`, yet you have described `#pragma startup`, `#pragma exit` and `#pragma warn`

Comment: @Toby he is just asking about pragma and has copied the content of a header file "I have been observing in some of the headers the use of pragma. But really not sure proper usage of it"

Comment: See my comments to the OP

Comment: Yeah I read that but there was no mention of pragma warning so I just answered it, also I am not a gold tag holder who could mark it as duplicate .