# C #pragma is preprocess or compile time operation?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, c-preprocessor

I have been working on GCC pragma types and it's operations. But I realized that pragmas can be used to command directly compiler. The confusion I am having is that # operations are part of preprocessing, for example

```
#if DEBUG
 /* statement one */
#elif RELEASE
 /* statement two */
#endif
```

if debug mode is activated, the compiler does not even compile and detect errors in statement two, but how does #pragma can directly command to the compiler?

Also If It is controlling the compiler, is there a way to do it without #pragmas? Because after preprocessing there is only C code left.

Comment: Because #pragma GCC optimize(...) can change optimization level.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of #pragma in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232785/use-of-pragma-in-c)

Comment: Pragmas are listed as preprocessor directives, but used to control the compiler: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html

Comment: I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Your last paragraph is specifically addressed in the link above - about introducing the `_Pragma` operator, which is *not* a preprocessor directive.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's not an actual operator either. GCC and Clang preprocessors replace `_Pragma` with `#pragma`.

Comment: gcc is not really doing preprocessing as a separate pass unless you ask it to, see [-no-integrated-cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) and even if you do, `#pragma` directives survive preprocessing intact and are still seen by the compiler (try it by running your source through `cpp`).

Comment: @dratenik they have to survive as they control compilation and code generation

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Well, they call it an operator. Also it can be emitted as a macro expansion unlike the `#pragma` directive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there a way to do it without #pragmas?

No, as far as I know.

> Because after preprocessing there is only C code left.

Turns out, at least GCC and Clang don't remove `#pragma` during preprocessing, and leave it for the compiler to handle. They also appear to replace `_Pragma` with `#pragma`.

You can see it by invoking them with the `-E` flag to output the preprocessed source.

> pragmas can be used to command directly compiler. The confusion I am having is that # operations are part of preprocessing

Yes, C++ is weird. The standard calls it a 'preprocessor directive', but doesn't define what it can or can't do. GCC developers decided to let it affect the compiler too.

Comment: So preprocess may leave command to control compiler process. But it highly depends on the compiler. Thanks for your valuable answer.

Answer (score 1):

#pragmas are compiler extensions and their behaviour is defined by the compiler. They start with `#` like preprocessor directives, but they are not one of them.  Some compilers have  other extensions like `gcc` `__attribute__` which can also set how the compiler compiles the source code and generates the output.

Comment: Pragmas in general are C standard: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.6 Specific pragmas might be an extension.